# Microsoft Bot not responding, although the server is hit and bot is provisioned

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit, microsoft-teams-js

I'm developing a Teams Command app using nodeJs, however, when I preview the app in teams and fire the helloWorld command, the server is hit, but it doesn't respond back.
I know it's hit because I added a log there, but somehow it do not get further than that.

this is my index.ts code:

```
import express from 'express';
import { commandApp } from "./internal/initialize";
import { TeamsBot } from "./teamsBot";
const index = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3100;

const teamsBot = new TeamsBot();
index.post("/api/messages", async (req, res) => {
    console.log('Endpoint was hit!') --> Nothing after this line works
    await commandApp.requestHandler(req, res, async (context) => {
        console.log("context: ", context);
        await teamsBot.run(context);
    });
});

// Start the server
index.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

I created the bot in azure and also did an app registration there in order to get the bot's secret. These infos I've added in a *.env* file in the server like this:
`BOT_ID=f5686cc4-c90c-49f4-89ea-d5fb5f92fa35 BOT_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxxxxxx`

I'm also using NGROK to create the tunnel from my localhost server to the Bot. This I have added in the bot endpoint in azure.

So, whenever I preview the Bot in Teams and hit the helloWorld command, I see this in my console:
[Console log result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rd7ye.png)

What am I missing?

Edit: For the server, I've used the one generated by teamsFX CLI and just converted it to use express instead of restify.

Edit 2: [Bot provisioned in Azure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LX32V.png)

Edit 3: After attaching a debugger and adding a breakpoint in the end of the server.post("/api/messages") function, I see that I'm getting a 401 error:

[401 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8dvB.png)

What am I missing? I've just created a new secret and pasted it into the BOT_PASSWORD prop in .env.

Comment: Could you please make sure, you have added Microsoft Teams as connected channel in Azure Bot? https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8NbN.png

Comment: Yes, it's there.

Comment: Here is the server code in case you want to check it: https://github.com/d-klotz/ms-bot-backend

Answer (score 0):

After long searching, I found out that somehow azure and teamsFx CLI is not able to handle changes that happen inside an Azure App Registration. I solved the 401 issue by creating from scratch a new Azure App Registration and then a new Azure Bot associated to the registration, and then used the BOT_ID and the newly generated BOT_PASSWORD and used those in my server.